# Kullback-Leibler Approximation of Unbounded by Bounded Densities

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory

Let $P$ denote a distribution on $[0,1]$ with density $p$, and let $KL(p \| q)$ denote the Kullback-Leiber divergence
$$
KL(p\|q) = \int_0^1 p \log \frac{p}{q} dx.
$$
Let $\mathcal C_{>0}([0,1])$ denote the collection of densities $q(x)$ such that $q(x)$ is *bounded away from 0*, i.e., $\inf_x q(x) > 0$ and continuous on all of $[0,1]$ (hence also bounded).

**Question**: Under what conditions does there exist a sequence $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ from $\mathcal C_{>0}([0,1])$ such that $KL(p \| q_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

**Partial progress**: If $p(x)$ is bounded above and continuous on $(0,1)$, then the problem is trivial: just take $q_n(x) \propto p(x) + \delta_n$ for any sequence $\delta_n \downarrow 0$. Then $KL(p \| q_n) = \log(1 + \delta_n) + \int p_0 \log \frac{p_0}{p_0 + \delta_n} \le \log(1 + \delta_n) \to 0$.

I can also make progress when $p(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$, bounded away from $0$, but unbounded at the endpoints using some simple constructions. For example, suppose $p(x)$ is unbounded near $0$ and let $q(x) \propto p(x)$ on some interval $I_\delta = (\delta, 1)$ and $q(x) \propto p(\delta)$ otherwise. The normalizing constant is given by $\delta p(\delta) + P I_\delta$, which converges to $1$ provided that $\delta p(\delta) \to 0$. If we add the additional condition that $P |\log p| < \infty$ then
$$
\lim_{\delta \to 0} KL(p \| q_\delta) =
\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_0^{\delta} p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{p(\delta)}
=
\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_0^\delta p(x) \log p(x) - P_0([0,\delta]) \log p(\delta) = 0.
$$
The conditions $P |\log p| < \infty$ and $\delta p(\delta) \to 0$ (e.g., $\delta p(\delta) \to 0$ must occur if $p(x)$ is monotone on some neighborhood of the endpoints, and possibly I can dispense with this condition by picking $\delta$ carefully) seem to cover just about any density I would encounter in practice. Dispensing with $P|\log p| < \infty$ would be desirable, however.

Comment: $\int p \log p < \infty$ seems necessary. Otherwise, take the case of monotonically decreasing densities which blow up near $0$, and take $\delta$ so small that $p > 1$ for $x < \delta.$ Then no matter what $q$ you pick, $\int_0^\delta p \log p - p \log q \ge \int_0^\delta p \log p - \log \sup q = \infty.$ (Also, btw, $p$ being monotone near the end points does not imply $\int p \log p $ is finite - take $p \propto 1/x\log^2 x.$) I don't know why you also demand $-\int p \log p < \infty,$ it seems that your argument works without this.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Being monotone near the endpoints doesn't imply the $P|\log p| < \infty$, but (I thought) it does imply my condition $\delta p(\delta) \to 0$. On a second pass, maybe it doesn't. If $\delta p(\delta)$ is bounded away from $0$ then the density doesn't integrate, so I think it should take some strange behavior for this condition to fail. If I can't get rid of my entropy condition, it would at least be nice to get rid of that condition.

Comment: I see. I guess your point about choosing $\delta$s judiciously holds - all you really need is some sequence such that $\delta_n p(\delta_n) \to 0,$ which exists if $\liminf_{\delta \to 0} \delta p(\delta) = 0.$ But of course if the $\liminf$ is positive then you have, for small enough $x$, $p(x) > c/x$ for some $c > 0,$ and then $\int p$ blows up, contradicting the fact that $p$ is a density.